# How do I remove a white border that only pops on my ThreeJS webpage in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I thought it might be a resizing window issue, for which I wrote a JS function, but that didn't seem to be the case. Any suggestions?

```html
/if the user resizes the window, the camera and renderer are updated
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
onWindowResize();
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
```

[image: Example of White Border]

Comment: I also want to note that the white border only appears when the user scrolls down on a web page, but when the user scrolls back up the border goes away.

Comment: I have experienced problems with reading innerWidth/Height on IOS and have a workaround - see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463449/window-innerwidth-incorrect-in-chrome-ios-87-0-4280-77-after-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing onWindowResize() and run again.